# Geth private POA network behaving strangely

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, websocket, geth-clique, private-ethereum

### The Setup

I have setup a private POA network using geth (v1.10.14).
My network configurations are as following;

1. BlockTime: 1sec
2. Consensus: Clique
3. Number of Signers: 3
4. Number of Miners: 3

I have started geth nodes using almost same command line arguments;

```
/usr/bin/geth \
--datadir /home/mt/.ethereum \
--networkid 2128 \
--nat extip:"x.x.x.x" \
--port 3030 \
--syncmode full \
--metrics --metrics.addr 0.0.0.0 --metrics.expensive \
--allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0xf09a72dBF7EfE9701591C2615728447A1325ec02 --password /home/mt/.ethereum/passkey/password.txt \
--http --http.corsdomain "" --http.port 8545 --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.api "eth,net,web3,txpool" \
--ws --ws.origins "" --ws.port 8546 --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" --ws.api "eth,net,web3" \
--mine --miner.etherbase 0 --miner.gasprice 0 --miner.gaslimit 9999999 \
--bootnodes "......"
```

Moreover; I am running above geth command as systemctl service.

### The Problems

1. I am observing each node via geth ipc console and sample output of `eth.blockNumber`; for all three nodes are as following;

###### Node 1 Output:

```
> setInterval(function () { console.log(eth.blockNumber) }, 3000);
> 16453
16455
16455
16455
16455
16455
16455
16455
16457
16457
16457
16457
621
621
621
621
621
621
16457
16457
16457
16459
16459
16459
16459
16459
16459
16461
16461
16461
16463
16464
16464
16464
16464
16464
16464
16466
```

###### Node 2 Output:

```
> setInterval(function () { console.log(eth.blockNumber) }, 3000);
>16454
16455
16455
16456
16456
16456
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
519
16457
16457
16457
16459
16459
16459
16459
16459
16459
16461
16461
16461
16463
16464
```

###### Node 3 Output:

```
> setInterval(function () { console.log(eth.blockNumber) }, 3000);
>16485
16485
16487
16487
16487
16489
16489
16489
16489
16489
16489
16489
16491
16491
16491
16491
16491
16491
16491
16493
16493
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
612
16493
16493
16493
16493
16493
16495
16495
16495
16495
```

- The output of `eth.blockNumber` drops to a lower number for a few seconds and then gets back to normal numbers.
- I have set the block time to `1 sec` but each new blocks take between 5 to 30+ seconds.
- I am repeatedly getting this error on Geth logs

```
INFO [12-28|21:21:20.359] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=0
INFO [12-28|21:21:20.359] Commit new mining work                   number=16642 sealhash=efe21b..9770a3 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="71.291µs"
WARN [12-28|21:21:20.359] Block sealing failed                     err="signed recently, must wait for others"
```

#### The bigger Problem

I have a simple NodeJS script that listnes for blocks by subscribing to `block` event on ethers.js websocket provider. But after few seconds the websocket connection closes and my script crashes.

What I am doing wrong here, and how do I keep my websocket connection stable.

## UPDATE

So using this script I am able to reconnect whenever the connection is closed.

```
const { WebSocket } = require("ws");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

function createWebSocket() {
  const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.5:8546");

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected. Reconnecting...");
    setTimeout(() => {
      provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(createWebSocket());
      startListening();
    }, 3000);
  });

  ws.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("WebSocket error: ", error);
  });

  return ws;
}

let provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(createWebSocket());

function startListening() {
  provider.on("block", (blockNumber) => {
    console.log("New block mined: ", blockNumber);
  });
}

startListening();
```

But the issue now is; some blocks missed out on re-connection and also some blocks are processed multiple time.

###### Output for above JS script

```
New block mined:  17000
New block mined:  17001
New block mined:  17001
New block mined:  17002
New block mined:  17003
Disconnected. Reconnecting...
New block mined:  17005
New block mined:  17006
New block mined:  17005
New block mined:  17006
New block mined:  17007
New block mined:  17008
New block mined:  17009
New block mined:  17010
New block mined:  17010
New block mined:  17011
New block mined:  17012
Disconnected. Reconnecting...
New block mined:  17014
New block mined:  17015
New block mined:  17014
New block mined:  17015
New block mined:  17016
New block mined:  17017
New block mined:  17018
New block mined:  17019
Disconnected. Reconnecting...
New block mined:  17020
New block mined:  17021
New block mined:  17022
New block mined:  17023
New block mined:  17024
New block mined:  17025
Disconnected. Reconnecting...
New block mined:  17026
New block mined:  17027
New block mined:  17028
New block mined:  17029
New block mined:  17030
New block mined:  17031
New block mined:  17031
New block mined:  17032
New block mined:  17033
New block mined:  17034
Disconnected. Reconnecting...
New block mined:  17035
New block mined:  17036
```